# VMware View Entitlements Cross-Domain

Tags: vdi, vmware-view

I know you need a two-way trust per VMware. However, this is not an option for us. Basically, domain A trusts domain B. Domain B doesn't trust domain A.

View Server is installed on domain A.

I can see the domain, but when I search for a user nothing comes up when trying to entitle. Is there somewhere I can enter credentials so that when it tries to search that domain it's authenticating and able to numerate the users/groups?

Answer (score 1):

In the forest where View is installed, create a Domain Local group.  You can add users/groups from domain B in to the Domain Local group on Domain A.  In View Admin, Entitle the pool with the Domain Local group.